# What is the meaning of @version annotation inside an .avdl file?

Tags: avro

In [this example](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/main/lang/java/compiler/src/test/idl/input/simple.avdl) from the official apache avro repository I see that there is a `@version("1.0.5")` on top.

However in the [specification](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/idl.html) this is not described anywhere.

What is the `@version` value refer to? Can this information somehow be included in the generated messages?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the @version annotation is part of the Apache Avro specification. If you look inside their repository, you will see many other files with this annotation.

- [Social.avdl](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/da98719ad84bad1ef71c17779ba6b3c482d84b2c/share/test/schemas/social.avdl#L20) (as an example)

  ```
  @version("1.0.5")
  @namespace("org.apache.avro.ipc.specific")
  protocol Social {
  ...
  ```

You can also see that the color of the @version annotation is not the same as other .avdl annotations (I.E. @namespace).

One possible thing this relates to, that I found inside their repository is the version of [nestedimport.avpr file](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/da98719ad84bad1ef71c17779ba6b3c482d84b2c/lang/java/idl/src/test/idl/output/nestedimport.avpr#L5).

```
{
  "protocol" : "nestedimport",
  "namespace" : "org.apache.avro.ipc.specific",
  "doc" : "Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one\nor more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file\ndistributed with this work for additional information\nregarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file\nto you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the\n\"License\"); you may not use this file except in compliance\nwith the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at\n\n    https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\n\nUnless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software\ndistributed under the License is distributed on an \"AS IS\" BASIS,\nWITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.\nSee the License for the specific language governing permissions and\nlimitations under the License.",
  "version" : "1.0.5",
  "types" : [ {
```